# How to get all entry's from elasticseach using apache camel?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf

Let's suppose i have elasticsearch instance like this:

```
 from("direct:index")
    .to("elasticsearch://local?operation=INDEX&indexName=twitter&

   indexType=tweet");
```

and i added 10 tweets, how can i get all list of this tweets from elasticsearch ? I tried something like this:

```
from("elasticsearch://local?operation=MULTIGET&indexName=twitter&    indexType=tweet").process(new MyProcessor())
   .to("direct:somewhere")
```

but it don't work, can u help me do this ? And what type of data it gonna be in processor ?

I need to get list of all tweets using apache camel DSL, can u help me do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but the [Camel Elastic](https://camel.apache.org/elasticsearch.html) page says that `MULTIGET`

> Retrieves the specified indexes type's specified in MultigetRequest and returns a MultigetResponse object in the body

So I guess you have to **provide a `MultigetRequest` object in your message body** and then execute the search in Elastic.

That would mean that you cannot use it directly as a Consumer with `from(...)`, but you would have to call it with `.to(...)` and make sure the message contains the correct body.